# Scale div on scroll - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

Working with this existing codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDqdJ). I want to add another statement whereby at a certain distance from the top of the page, an already animated div then changes in scale whilst moving.

Really struggling with the syntax and to increment the scale of the animated div on the scroll. I'm guessing that I will need to use css transform, but need some help!

Please see below for js example:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $box = $("#box");

$window.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollTop);
    if (scrollTop >= 250 && scrollTop < 400) {
      $box.css({top: -250 + scrollTop});      
    } else if(scrollTop >= 400 && scrollTop < 460) {
      $box.css({left: (10+(scrollTop-400)/2)+"%"})
    } else if(scrollTop >= 460 && scrollTop < 580) {
      $box.css({top: (50+(scrollTop-460)/2)+"%"})
    } else if(scrollTop >= 580 && scrollTop < 620) {
      $box.css('transform', 'scale(' + whateverTheScaleShouldBe + ')');
    }
});
```

Here is the html structure -

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row3">
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated! :)

J

Comment: What problems are you having? You'd affect the `transform` scale like you would any property in javascript. As for scaling it, `transform` has a value of `scale` that you can use like so: `transform:scale(.5)`, which would make the element half of the size it originally was

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to use transform:scale so that the scale value is slowly decreased based on the scroll height

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: "Working with this existing codepen"... but where *is* the codepen?

Comment: I'm struggling with how to alter the transform scale figure based on scroll - $box.css({transform:scale(1.1)}) - So instead of 1.1 I believe there needs to be some logic to calculate one point decrement in scale based on scroll.

Comment: JS Fiddle shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: scale is not defined`

Comment: Hi Dan, I understand that line is breaking the script. I'm looking for a fix to adjust the scale based on scrolltop position. Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but there you go: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L52z69wa/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code:

```
$box.css({transform:scale(1.1)})
```

...is that the value is incorrect. The value to set for the CSS property should be a string. As it is currently, the code is trying to call a `scale` function in your JavaScript, which probably doesn't exist. If you want to use the CSS function `scale`, replace the code with this:

```
$box.css({transform: 'scale(1.1)'});
```

Or more simply:

```
$box.css('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
```

...then you'll change the CSS scale. You're probably also wanting to use a dynamic value for the `scale` CSS function. Doing that will be a matter of making the string dynamic:

```
$box.css('transform', 'scale(' + whateverTheScaleShouldBe + ')');
```

This `whateverTheScaleShouldBe` will be whatever your calculation is; it's not clear from your question *how* you want the scale to change as you scroll. If you wanted the scale to linearly grow by `0.1` per `100px`, as an example, you could do this:

```
scaleAmt = 1.0 + (scrollTop / 100);
$box.css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleAmt + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jacob. I want the box to decrease in scale based on how far from say 560px from the top of the page (scrollTop) is. So say when we are at 561 from the top, the scale would be 0.99. I hope that has made it clearer

Comment: It's still not clear what "based on" means, sorry. I'd suggest coming up with a function that takes the `scrollTop` and returns the scale number.

Comment: Your last edit was close to what I was hoping for. I have updated the pen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDqdJ how could I adjust this  so it smoothly grows by 0.1 per 1px?

Comment: `/ 100` means `0.01` per pixel; just divide by `10` instead to make it `0.1` per pixel. Just play with the formula to get what you want.

Comment: Trying to use this example in another similar way, the animation is linked to scrollTop, but say if you scroll the page faster, it messes the animation up. Would there be anyway around this Jacob?

Comment: What do you mean by "messes the animation up?" This isn't really animation, but making the transform change based on the scroll position. To make a smooth animation would take a different approach. Hopefully someone gives an answer that's using real animation. I may not have time today.